# jquery and the style properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

where can i get informations how styles are written in jquery.

for example it is not the normal way z-index 
it is zIndex... and so on..

fontWeight..

Answer (score 3):

No need. You can use the CSS style.

```
$("#ID").css({
    'z-index': 100,
    'height': '100px'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not jQuery, it's the way JavaScript handles it.

Here's a chart:

http://codepunk.hardwar.org.uk/css2js.htm

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple.

All dashes are replaced by [camelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camelcase).

Therefore, every time you see a dash, remove it and make the next letter upper case.

Alternatively, you can specify the styles as strings within the JSON keys, and use exactly the same names as CSS.

For example: `{ "z-index": 4, "background-color": "red" }`.

Comment: One notable exception is `float` (styleFloat/cssFloat). I think there might be one or two other exceptions like this, but I can't think of any others right now...

Comment: In plain Javascript, that's true, but not in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

See here also. I have seen cases where the browser (Safari) will only accept it with hyphen...

[jQuery CSS](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/css#namevalue)